# BD Access, campo Data

Tags: banco-de-dados, validação, inserir, microsoft-access

Numa BD do Access com um campo "Data", ao inserir dados nesse campo, é possível fazer algo para que datas passadas há mais 3 dias sejam rejeitadas? Se possível, ensinam-me por favor!
Na verdade só consegui fazer com que datas futuras não sejam inseridas, através da seguinte expressão na propriedade "Regra de validação": <=Data(). É que os dados são recolhidos, diariamente, por meio de formulário do Outlook e há quem manda com data muito antiga. Obrigado!

Comment: Você já tentou desenvovler algo? Dificilmente vão te entregar algo pronto. Tente mostrar o que já tentou

Comment: Ok, na verdade só consegui fazer com que datas futuras não sejam inseridas, através da seguinte expressão na propriedade "Regra de validação": <=Data(). É que os dados são recolhidos, diariamente, por meio de formulário do Outlook e há quem manda com data muito antiga. Obrigado!

Comment: adicione sua tentativa no corpo da pergunta, tente `(Date()) <= (Date() - 3) `

Comment: correção ´(Date()) >= (Date() - 3)´

Comment: Obrigado amigo @HebertdeLima de Lima, experimentei a sua sugestão, não deu certo mas, confesso que me ajudou bastante pois, permitiu-me pensar e experimentar a expressão '>=Data()-3', com a qual a BD impeça as datas antigas pretendidas mas, infelizmente, aceita datas futuras (menos mal). Assim, vou lutando mais, embora sinto-me muito satisfeito, obrigado!

Comment: vc quer que a data máxima seja o dia atual, e a data antiga no máximo 3 dias? sua condição seria `hoje >=Date()-3  e hoje <= Date()`?

Comment: Valeu, caro @HebertdeLima ajudaste-me muito, estou feliz, obrigado! Mas, importa dizer que a condição com as palavras "hoje" não ajudou assim, experimentei eliminar e deu certo, quer dizer, usei a seguinte:>=Data()-3 E <=Data().

Comment: Bendita hora que encontrei esse espaço com pessoas maravilhosas com o Sr. @HebertdeLima, tenho a certeza que vou aprender muito e pouco a pouco realizando o meu sonho de entender de Programação, embora, infelizmente de momento, que tenho muito pouco para contribuir, pois estou ainda no nível 0 ou 1/1000 (rs). Obrigado, conto convosco para outras questões e que o Senhor nos abençoe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fechar a questão:
`>= Date()- 3 E <= Date()`

Comment: Obrigado caro @HebertdeLima, parabéns e espero por mais contribuições suas na outra pergunta que submeti. Bom dia!